# I am trying to map a Generic Type for Unity

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am trying to add a dependency to a class property using Unity Configuration and also the types I am trying to inject are generic.  I had a "Google" about and found I need to use the '1 syntax.  I am following a tutorial by David Hayden on the Validation Application block BUT, instead of programmatically registering the type I am setting it up through the config file.

```
<typeAliases>
    <!-- Lifetime manager types -->
    <typeAlias alias="singleton" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager,Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />
    <typeAlias alias="external" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager,Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />
    <typeAlias alias="IValidator`1" type="MySerivice.IValidator`1,MyService" />
    <typeAlias alias="VABValidator`1" type="MySerivice.VABValidator`1,MyService" />
    <typeAlias alias="MyService" type="MySerivice.MyService,MyService" />
</typeAliases>
```

Then I register the mappings and properties here:

```
<types>    
  <type type="MyService">
    <typeConfig extensionType="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.TypeInjectionElement Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration">
      <property name="Validator" propertyType="IValidator`1"/>
    </typeConfig>
  </type>
  <type type="IValidator`1" mapTo="VABValidator`1">
    <lifetime type="singleton" />
  </type>
</types>
```

Inside the MyService I have the following Property:

```
private IValidator<RegExpressionObject> validator;

[Dependency]
public IValidator<RegExpressionObject> Validator
{
    get { return validator; }
    set { validator = value; }
}
```

When I run this however I get the following exception which is really making me scratch my head:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   property Validator on type MyService
>   is of type IValidator'1, and cannot be
>   injected with a value of type
>   IValidator'1

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for this syntax:

```
<typeAlias alias="VABValidator`1" 
           type="MySerivice.VABValidator`1
                [[Assembly.Namespace.RegExpressionObject,Assembly]],MyService"/>
```

That will specify the type of your generic parameter and allow you to inject it.

This functionality is not very well documented :)

Comment: Absolutely Brilliant.  Thank you very much for you time.  It is greatly appreciated.  :-)  Spot on!